# "Share" links on the FAQ point result in dead links

Tags: bug, status-completed

For example, the FAQ shows `http://stackoverflow.com/newfaq#reputation` as the link to share for the reputation section of the FAQ, but this results in a dead link

Comment: The entire `/newfaq` section is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a result of swapping the faq to the new format (though not completely, obviously), fixed in the next build.